# Non-Continuous nor monotonic function integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification

I have a question with regards to the solution to the following problem:

Let $f$ be defined on $[-1,1]$ by $f(x)=sin(1/x)$ if $x\neq 0$ and $0$ if $x=0$.

The solution is:

Let $\epsilon>0$  Let $D$ be the dissection $D=$ $\{$ $-1,x_1,x_2$,...,$\frac{-\epsilon}{8},\frac{\epsilon}{8}$,$x_{m+1}$....,$x_n=1$ $\}$
Since $f$ is continuous when $x\neq0$ it is integrable on $[-1,\frac{\epsilon}{8}$$]$ so we arrange the dissection $D_1=$ $\{$ $x_0,x_1....,x_m$ ,$\frac{\epsilon}{8}$ $\}$ to be such that $U(f,D_1)-L(f,D_1)< \frac{\epsilon}{4}$....

Basically you do the same thing with $[\frac{\epsilon}{8},1]$ and $[\frac{\epsilon}{8},\frac{\epsilon}{8}]$and then observe that $U(f,D)-L(f,D)<\epsilon$

The question I have is, why is $D$ a valid dissection? and why can we assume that $\frac{\epsilon}{8}$ $<1$? Aren't we supposed to show it holds for all $\epsilon?$ Whats the logic behind this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be valid for all $\epsilon>0$, but actually it suffices proving that for all $\epsilon>0$ smaller than a fixed positive value (in this case $8$), since then it would work also for bigger $\epsilon$ trivially.

On $[-\frac{\epsilon}{8},\frac{\epsilon}{8}]$ you are arguing that the maximum of the function is $1$ and the minimum $-1$, so the difference between the Upper Integral and Lower Integral is exactly $2\frac{\epsilon}{4}$. This, combined with the bound on the differences on the other two parts (which you got by continuity), gives that U and L differ at most by $\epsilon$.

Comment: ahh okay, because if we assume it holds for $\epsilon<8$ then we can just repeat the same argument for $\epsilon<9,10,11....$ etc and so it holds for all $\epsilon>0$, right?

Comment: Actually, if you already proved that you can find a dissection for which $U-L<\epsilon_0$ for some $\epsilon_0<8$, then for every $\epsilon\geq8$, using the same dissection, you get $U-L<\epsilon_0<8\leq\epsilon$ and you are done.

Comment: that makes perfect sense, have a beautiful day.